# One CPU at 100% at all times

Tags: cpu-load, system-monitor

For some reason one of my CPUs is always at 100% usage. Can anyone tell what the problem is from the pictures?

[image: System Monitor resources view]

[image: Processes showing no serious CPU usage]

[image: System Monitor showing 100% CPU usage and switching to another CPU]

Thanks

Comment: I've seen this happen after a blanket font change in an old copy of Librewriter.  What version system/Libre office are you running?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `ps auxk -pcpu | head`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me today:

[image: one cpu at 100 percent.png]

From conky display the process ID is 14633, so in the terminal use:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Python$ ps -o ppid=14633
14633
17412
 3140
[1]+  Done                    gedit gmail-list-msg.py
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Python$ ps -s -p 14633
  UID   PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
    0 14633 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffffffffffff 0000000000000000 R    ?          9:16 [kworker/4:0]
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Python$ ps -s -p 3140
  UID   PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
 1000  3140 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000001000 0000000180010000 Sl   ?          0:07 /usr/lib/gnome
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Python$ ps -s -p 17412
  UID   PID          PENDING          BLOCKED          IGNORED           CAUGHT STAT TTY        TIME COMMAND
 1000 17412 0000000000000000 0000000000010000 0000000000380004 000000004b817efb Ss   pts/19     0:00 bash
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/Python$
```

The 100% CPU usage was caused by using:

```
gedit gmail-list.msg.py &
```

`gedit` is used all the time as a background process and this is the first time I've seen 100% usage.

- After closing `gedit` the offending process: `kworker/4:0` is still using 100% of one CPU.
- After closing `gnome-terminal` the offending process is still using 100% of one CPU.
- After opening a new terminal using `sudo kill 14633` doesn't help.
- After using `sudo kill 3140` there is no change.
- Using `sudo kill 17412` has no effect.

The only option left is to reboot and monitor if using `gedit Xxxx &` causes problem to reoccur.

---

### First Reboot

After first reboot the problem shifted from CPU 4 to CPU 0 and offending `kworker` changed from `4` to `3`.

Gnome terminal was automatically called by Startup Applications which seemed a regression of this bug: [Debian Bug report logs - #594245
gnome-terminal using a lot of cpu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=594245)

I deactivated `gnome-terminal` from Startup Applications and rebooted

---

### Second Reboot

After second reboot no CPU is running at 100%.

I notice another problem where CPU frequency is running close to maximum of 3,000 MHz when it should be around 1,000 MHz with `powersave` governor active (which it is).

I also notice a crash report on `pstree` which is called by one of my bash script daemons that didn't wake up properly. I filed the automatic data collection bug report with Ubuntu and then rebooted.

---

### Third Reboot

The BIOS start up screen seems frozen. Do a 1 second power button press and it acts like a 10 second power button press (hard power off).

Press power button again for cold boot (no longer a Restart / Warm Boot).

---

### Power up after Shutdown

All is well again. Unknown what exactly went wrong but hopefully the documented steps helps others diagnose transient errors.